# What does "Prout necessitas ferat atque experientia suffragetur" translate to in English?

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation, translation-explanation

What would this latin sentence mean : "Prout necessitas ferat atque experientia suffragetur" ?
No idea...
Note: found in [this link](http://www.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/la/apost_constitutions/documents/hf_p-xii_apc_19470202_provida-mater-ecclesia.html)

Comment: Welcome to the Community! Have you tried searching for each individual word in a [Latin Dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why)? It's great to post a question like this when you need help with a translation, but a good dictionary can help in advance of that - it will help you understand the translation and aid you with other phrases in the future.

Comment: Well, I understand "necessitas","ferre", suffragi" etc, but the mix of those words, as presented here, look not understandable to me. "necessitas ferat" or "necessitas fert", for example, what could it mean ? I browsed dictionaries but found nothing. I could understand "experientiae suffragor", but not "experientia suffragetur"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an official English translation at the link you provided (labelled "EN" at the top right-hand side), which gives **"as need arises and in the light of experience"** as the official Vatican translation of this phrase.

Translated overly literally, it means *"according as necessity carries and experience counsels"*.

Comment: "experiences are agreed with" ← I think this should rather be: "as experience counsels"

Comment: Oops, missed that *suffragor* is a deponent verb (and it's a singular form to boot!).

Comment: I didn't know verb "ferre" could mean "arise"... The English translation seems to me far apart the real meaning

Comment: @Andrew oh, you'd be surprised at all the things *ferre* can mean...